# how to fix the inflation another R.layout

Tags: android

I have `mainactivity` and `gridimageactivity` I Noticed that gridimageactivity is inflating the mainactivity layout. I want to add new buttons and thing in the R.main_activity.

this is in mainactivity as you noticed I commented the layout however the app is still displaying textviews and images.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        GetDataJSON gj = new GetDataJSON();
        gj.execute();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is gridadapter I guess what is causing problem

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new ViewHolder();
```

I am calling gridimage like this 
`GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);`

My question: I want to be able to inflate my mainactivity to add toolbar however the inflating in gridview is preventing me. how to fx that ?

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridImages> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages = new ArrayList<GridImages>();



  public GridViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages) {
        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridImages);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGridImages = mGridImages;
    }


    /**
     * Updates grid data and refresh grid items.
     * @param mGridData
     */
    public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages) {
        this.mGridImages = mGridImages;
    }
```

Comment: add button `public class GridViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("DynAdded Button");
        layout.addView(btnTag);
    }
}`

Comment: added as an answer it will be clearer for me and ill upvote you

Answer (score 1):

As commented, please try the following (sample for adding a button inside GridViewActivity which uses layout_main.xml).

```
public class GridViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Dynamic Added Button");
        layout.addView(btnTag);
    }
}
```

However, you should check if it works for your project or not.

UPDATE:

**row_grid.xml:**

My answer in your previous question:

```
customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
```

Comment: I added my gridview activity I am already extending arrayadapter. .do I add oncreate method ? how the button will work ?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify that? I don't understand your comment

Comment: check my edit please I added my GridViewAdapter class. in the class I am extending  ` extends ArrayAdapter<GridImages>` how ever in your example you said `extends AppCompatActivity` how to do that then ?

Comment: GridViewAdapter class is a non-activity class, my class is GridViewActivity which you mentioned `gridimageactivity` at the beginning of your question.

Comment: gridimageactivity in the example is GridViewActivity  in my code. bnk useually when people use adapter how they handle inflating layouts ?

Comment: Sorry! I really cannot understand your issue here

Comment: okay .. the above class gridview activity. can you fix it so My `activity_main.xml` layout  is visible ?

Comment: Is it invisible? Show your screenshots for more clarification

Comment: how to explain that to you. I have activity_main.xml and grid_item_layout.xml okay ? I want to load/inflate activit_main.xml but its doesnt load. this grid_item_layout.xml  is loading instead. understand me now ? the grid_item is part of GridViewAdapter and this class is preventing activity_main.xml  to load

Comment: In my answer to your previous question, you will see the line `customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);` the `R.layout.row_grid` perhaps like your `grid_item_layout.xml`

Comment: I will paste the row_grid content in this answer (too long for comment)

Comment: activit_main.xml still loading. My project only has one activity that is MainActivity

Comment: In your code you calling `layout.row_grid` and you called             holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
your only layout is is row_grid,xml?

Comment: I have 2 layout files: activity_main.xml and row_grid.xml

Comment: the same here.. my problem in my code if I comment `// activity_main` the app still working. is that normal ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know really. Here is my GitHub full source code, you can take a look. https://github.com/ngocchung/GridView Goodluck!

Comment: I only have one MainActivity.java which uses activity_main.xml which contains the gridview, why remove it?

Comment: I am busy now, so cannot help. You can refer my GitHub project